# Сортировка постов по убыванию

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

У меня имеет массив с обьектами. Где хранится id, text, sub. Где sub - кол-во подписчиков. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы в консоль сначала выводились только обьекты с большим кол-во sub, то есть по убыванию. Использую метод sort(), но он их отнимает

```js
const posts = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Hi',
    sub: 4
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Hello',
    sub: 7
  }
]


posts.sort(function(subone, subtwo) {
  console.log(subone.sub - subtwo.sub)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых надо поменять местами `subone.sub` и `subtwo.sub`

Во-вторых, метод ожидает что что-то будет возвращено, какое-то значение: -1, 1 или 0. А вы ничего не возвращаете. Надо `return subtwo.sub - subone.sub` а не `console.log`